# Django file input from Forms not reaching model

Tags: python, django

I am a noob in django and am not able to figure out the issue in my code. Basically I am trying to upload some images to my server using a form. Whenever I save the form, it is only taking the default image specified in my model, not the images I uploaded in my form.

print(request.Files) before calling form.is_valid() is giving output as:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'id_image01': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image01.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'id_image02': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image02.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'id_image03': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image04.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'id_image04': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image07.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

which I presume says that the image is correctly loaded in the memory.

My code goes like this:

views.py

```
def create_puzzle(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES)
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            puzzleImages= form.save(commit=False)
            puzzleImages.username= request.user.username
            puzzleImages.save()
            return redirect('/puzzle/index.html')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'puzzle/create_puzzle.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

my Forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('birthday_message', 'video_url', 'image01',
            'image02', 'image03','image04',
            'image05', 'image06', 'image07',
            'image08', 'image09', 'image10')
        captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        public_key='###########',
        private_key='###########',
)
```

my models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image01 = models.ImageField(default='default/image01.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image02 = models.ImageField(default='default/image02.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image03 = models.ImageField(default='default/image03.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image04 = models.ImageField(default='default/image04.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image05 = models.ImageField(default='default/image05.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image06 = models.ImageField(default='default/image06.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image07 = models.ImageField(default='default/image07.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image08 = models.ImageField(default='default/image08.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image09 = models.ImageField(default='default/image09.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image10 = models.ImageField(default='default/image10.png', upload_to=user_directory_path)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    birthday_message=models.CharField(default='Happy Birthday Special One!!!', max_length=500)
    video_url=models.CharField(default='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9jl1yLURp4', max_length=100)


    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #print (self.image01)
        #print(self.birthday_message)

        if not self.id:
            self.image01 = self.compressImage(self.image01, "image01")
            self.image02 = self.compressImage(self.image02, "image02")
            self.image03 = self.compressImage(self.image03, "image03")
            self.image04 = self.compressImage(self.image04, "image04")
            self.image05 = self.compressImage(self.image05, "image05")
            self.image06 = self.compressImage(self.image06, "image06")
            self.image07 = self.compressImage(self.image07, "image07")
            self.image08 = self.compressImage(self.image08, "image08")
            self.image09 = self.compressImage(self.image09, "image09")
            self.image10 = self.compressImage(self.image10, "image10")
        super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @abhisekG Can you share your html page please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause of the issue. I wanted to render form fields manually and was using  to get the files. It would pass the text inputs normally but when it came to files, it would not validate them. So, instead of having a tag such as:

```
<input name="id_image03" type="file" class="form-control" id="id_image03">
```

I did:

```
{{ form.image03 }}
```

That was it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Please add below line of code in your template
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
-----
 ----
  ----
  </form>
```

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav, Thank you for your answer. I already have it:
<form id= "create-puzzle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}